# OpenPop Can't read who received the email

Tags: pop3, openpop

I am trying to create a dropbox email for my website.
So I have created a catch all email address: dropbox@domain.com 
Each customer on the website will then be given a dropbox email each ex: dropbox123@domain.com 
Customers can then bcc emails to the given email and it will automatically enter the stuff into the notes.
When Reading through the emails caught by dropbox@domain.com I would then like to determine which email address was put in bcc and react accordingly.

Now to the question: 
When opening up the email directly on the server I can see the raw email in notepad and the first line says:

```
Received: from ([209.85.215.58]) for <dropbox123@domain.com> with MailEnable 
Catch-All Filter;
Sun, 4 Jan 2015 21:16:44 +0000
```

When reading this email through OpenPop I get this:

```
Received: from ([209.85.215.58]) for with MailEnable Catch-All Filter; Sun, 4 Jan 
2015 21:22:35 +0000
```

So the "for" email address is not part of the openpop message header.
It does not matter if I take the OpenPop.Mime.Message.RawMessage or I try to read the header.

Is this a bug in the OpenPop or am I missing the obvious?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in OpenPOP (it should not be changing the values of the headers). I would recommend submitting a bug report to https://github.com/foens/hpop and hopefully the developer will implement a fix for you.

If not, I would suggest using [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) which does not have this problem.